# SoundManager2 with iOS - Doesn't play sound onClick event

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, ipad, soundmanager2

I'm trying to make a sound play on a "onClick" event using SoundManager2.  Everything is working fine with IE, Chrome and FireFox.  But when trying on an iPad or an iPhone, the sound doesn't play.

Here's (part) my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    soundManager.debugMode = false;
    soundManager.url = 'soundmanager2.swf';
    soundManager.onload = function() {
        soundManager.createSound({
            id:'car',
            url:'audio/car.mp3',
            useHTML5Audio: true,
            preferFlash: false
        });
</script>
```

Here's (part) my HTML code:

```
<area shape='polygon'   coords='74,164,203,96,397,161,385,236,286,237,259,290,167,288,166,237,77,233' 
    onclick="soundManager.play('car')">
```

Comment: swf is adobe flash.  flash is not on ios

Comment: SoundManager2 will determine if it should use Flash or HTML5 based on the user agent.  If someone is browsing using an iOS device, SoundManager will go with HTML5 (audio) instead of Flash.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your url is not correct for the path to the audio file `audio/car.mp3`

When I work with `UIWebViews` and I load images from my app's resources if I just say the name of the image they won't display but if I say the name of the image in the html file and then when I load the html file I say something like this

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlstring baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]
```

Then it works. The key is the `baseURL:`

When you load your html into your web view (I'm assuming that's what you're doing) try using the `baseURL` method I posted above.

Comment: [Do not use signatures, salutations or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)